# simple IParallelEnumerable<T> tutorial

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I recently found that a collection has a methon AsParallel() that returns IParallelEnumerable. I never worked with this type and some how I don't get it from google. Can you pls give a simple example on using it?
What I'm trying to do is to have a for like loop and proccess each element without modifing it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This paradigm is also called PLinq, so try searching for that:
http://www.google.dk/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=plinq

One of the first hits is
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for "parallel extension library" guides.

If you use the IParallelEnumerable should be able to just start your processing like:

```
var result = source.AsParallel().Where(s => IsSomeCondition(s));
var result = source.AsParallel().Select(s => new Something(s));
```

There should be a method to do parallel for and parallel foreach, too.